# Can not open an Excel document from SharePoint

Tags: excel, sharepoint, ms-office, wss

My problem occurs only for Excel files from a SharePoint 2003 WSS2.
I meet the problem with all versions of Internet Explorer

**Details of the problem:**

When clicking on the Excel file (**screen 1**) a pop-up appears offering the choice to open or save the file (**screen 2**).

Saving the file works fine but if I select "Open" the pop-up close, then the page becomes blank. And my document does not open :(.

This problem does not occur when opening files with a different file extension.
With the same browser, if I open an excel file not stored in Sharepoint (i-e in another website), I can open the file successfully. Despite my attempt multiple searches on the net I hope to find my solution with you.

The problem may have started with the installation of Office 2013 on the computer, but I'm not sure.

**Screen 1**

[image]

**Screen 2**

[image]

The translation of the buttons are "Enregistrer" = "Save" "Enregistrer sous " = "Save as" "Ouvrir" = "Open"

Comment: I think this question is more relevant to SuperUser, not StackOverflow since it isn't about programming, but support.  With that being said: Has it ever worked?  What happens if you try it from another browser?  What brower are you having problems with?  What about from another computer with the same browser?  Also: This is a predominantly English-speaking site, it would really help to provide translations of messages and buttons in screenshots.

Comment: The translation of the buttons are
"Enregistrer" = "Save"
"Enregistrer sous " = "Save as"
"Ouvrir" = "Open"
On the other browser will download the file, but I think this is the default behavior of other browser (no pop-up).
From another computer the problem is the same

Comment: I saw you said you installed Office recently Did you recently install a 64 bit office product on the same box as a 32 bit office product or vice versa?

Comment: I have installed Office 2013 32 bits, and my computer OS is 64 bits. You think this is a problem ?